Issue with Dequeuing Custom Cells in Main Storyboard
I'm encountering an NSInternalInconsistencyException when trying to dequeue custom cells designed in XIB files in my main storyboard. The error message is:
unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cellCustom - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard. 
What I Tried

Registered the cells properly: Confirmed the reuse identifier matches the one used to dequeue.
Removing and re-adding references: Tried removing and re-adding the cells from build phases.
Testing with other storyboards: The issue only occurs in the main storyboard. It works fine in other storyboards.
Added prototype cells in main storyboard: When using prototype cells in the main storyboard, everything works fine.
Checked if my custom class matches my xib class
Checked if my outlets are connected to the view properly and not the file owner
Tried clean building and clearing derived data

Code
Registering Cells in ViewController

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellCustom")
    
    let anotherNib = UINib(nibName: "AnotherCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(anotherNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellAnother")
}

Dequeuing Cells

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellCustom", for: indexPath) as? CustomCell else {
            fatalError("Unable to dequeue cell with identifier: cellCustom")
        }
        return cell
    } else {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellAnother", for: indexPath) as? AnotherCell else {
            fatalError("Unable to dequeue cell with identifier: cellAnother")
        }
        return cell
    }
}

Error Message
2024-07-27 22:18:23.234513+0530 test[4203:4352355] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:usingPresentationValues:], UITableView.m:9818
2024-07-27 22:18:23.242276+0530 test[4203:4352355] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cellCustom - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1805afc60 0x197ddfee4 0x181d54c80 0x182da33bc 0x182a4263c 0x10481e364 0x104824598 0x182ac7f8c 0x182cb284c 0x182aebea8 0x1829c4428 0x1829d4174 0x184054520 0x184047294 0x18405acc8 0x18406379c 0x1829ae708 0x18055b76c 0x18052c974 0x180527efc 0x18053b174 0x1a107a988 0x182d3da88 0x182ad6f78 0x196ec7ee4 0x104be2bd0 0x104be2b48 0x104bfe3dc 0x10680c4d0)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Are you sure the tableview instance that you are registering the nib on is the same instance on which you are trying to dequeue the cell?

Could you print tableView in viewDidLoad and tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) as suggested in previous comment? Is the Storyboard localized? I remember that in old Xcode version they were duplicated instead of using a String file. And I made a lot of changed on a localized one, but not on the main one...

@Paulw11 Yes I am sure

@Larme Yeah the storyboard is actually localized but we use string localization too . Is that the issue ? The table view is  <UITableView: 0x10548aa00; frame = (8 122; 359 242); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x2830a95f0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x283ef3e00>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {359, 358}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}; dataSource: <test.ViewController: 0x105814800>>

You need to print the tableview in both places as suggested by Larme and ensure that they have the same address

@Paulw11 They have the same address I checked twice

@bumblebee - we don't have much information to go on. "only occurs in the main storyboard" ... is this the Initial View Controller? If not, how are you instantiating / navigating to it? Is cellForRowAt in an Extension or in the view controller class? Presumably, you've already set breakpoints to confirm .register(...) is executing (and is doing so before cellForRowAt executes)? Can you make a copy of the project and strip it down to create a [mre]?

@DonMag This project is really big with over 100+ screens in main storyboard itself . Stripping it down is really hard imo . Yes this is the initial view controller and it is instantiated using segue . cellForRow at is in the view controller class . I have confirmed the register function is executing .

@bumblebee -- hmm... if it's the initial view controller in the main storyboard -- how is it being instantiated using segue? It makes me wonder if you are editing the wrong class?
